# Post offline notifications from my website

Tags: facebook, post, offline

I have a website (www.cadi.com.tr in Turkish) and a facebook page for my followers (fans of the website) with about 10000 members. Right now, everyday I log into my facebook account (http://www.facebook.com/#!/pages/CADI/20643040386?ref=ts), then go to my website and "share" new posts to my facebook account. I do not want to go through the whole hassle of integrating facebook connect to my website. What I would like to do is: have my website automatically stream/share new posts to my facebook page when someone writes a new blog on my site.  I seem to have found that I can grant my website "offline" access to post directly, but I have yet to find any sample code for this. Am I correct in thinking that I can give my website access to stream to my web page even though I am not logged in? Does anyone have any sample code or useful documentation for this (preferably in php)?

I thank everyone in advance

Swayze

Answer (score 1):

I found http://basiccodes.kunals.com/2011/02/10/facebook-apps-offline-access-post-to-pages/

Maybe it will help you in getting this to work.